# ubercart template email addresses hard coded in template

Tags: ubercart

I have inherited an app which has an email hard coded into an ubercart template here /sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates/uc-order--customer.tpl.php

How can I set up this email to be accessible from an adminitratable page instead of being hard coded so it can easily be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 components here: capture/store a setting for you email & insert it into your template.

Since it's a part of your template settings, I'd suggest `hook_form_alter()` the order template setting form to capture/store a variable:

```
function MYMODULE_form_uc_order_settings_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['MYMODULE_uc_order_template_email'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Template Email'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_uc_order_template_email', 'test@example.com'),
    '#description' => t("Template Email"),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
}
```

The next component is to take that variable an inject it into your template. Using the example above, the variable `MYMODULE_uc_order_template_email` will now be available. Use a [pre-process function](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ubercart!uc_order!uc_order.module/function/template_preprocess_uc_order/7) to insert a email variable into template. Add this to your theme's **template.php**:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_uc_order(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_email'] = variable_get('MYMODULE_uc_order_template_email', 'test@example.com');
}
```

Lastly, copy over **uc-order--customer.tpl.php** to your theme directory (so UC updates don't wipe away your customizations), flush the cache (to pickup the new template), and, insert `$my_email` into your **uc-order--customer.tpl.php** copy.

Comment: That isn't hardcoding; the function [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) allows you to specify a **default** in case the variable hasn't been configured yet. In the above example, the order template form now contains an email field from which you can configure the email to be used in the template.

Comment: how can I add validation so that only a real email is put into the settings form? thanks